# How to customize kendo ui grid pager size?

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Here is the [Kendo UI for Angular pager](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/paging/)

The pager template is:

```
<ng-template kendoPagerTemplate let-totalPages="totalPages" let-currentPage="currentPage">
        <kendo-pager-prev-buttons></kendo-pager-prev-buttons>
        <kendo-slider
            [showButtons]="false"
            tickPlacement="none"
            [max]="totalPages"
            [min]="1"
            (valueChange)="sliderChange($event)"
            [value]="currentPage">
        </kendo-slider>
        <kendo-pager-info></kendo-pager-info>
        <kendo-pager-next-buttons></kendo-pager-next-buttons>
        <kendo-pager-page-sizes [pageSizes]="[5, 10, 40]"></kendo-pager-page-sizes>
     </ng-template>
```

What I want is to reduce the pager height to the desired value, say 25px. How?

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your component's CSS file:

```
::ng-deep kendo-grid kendo-pager {
    height: 25px;
}
```

`::ng-deep` is used to allow the styling to break encapsulation and affect styles inside a component contained in your component.